# Installation of an unattended program .exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have the following code:

```
@echo off

if not exist %SYSTEMDRIVE%\WINDOWS\system32\msvcr100.dll (

"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\vcredist_x86.exe" /SP- /VERYSILENT
)
```

But when I run it, I need to mark options at the time of installation, how could I start an installation by skipping all those options automatically?

[image: options]

Comment: Well, I would begin with reading the documentation and try to find out whether there are certain command line switches to predefine the options...

Comment: This will depend on what you're installing. Installers will ha e their own arguments, and hopefully they're documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want it to do:

`"2010 SP1\vcredist_x86.exe" /passive /norestart`